# Auto refresh or timer in Multiview asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have multiple Views using Multiview in ASP.NET and I have topContent, leftContent, rightContent and lastly, the middleContent is the content with Multiview. So, all content are same except that the middleContent will be changing once clicked on... example click on the leftContent(navigation part) then will change the middleContent Multiview to a particular View.

Is it possible to just auto refresh the middleContent (Multiview part) using C# coding or Javascript without clicking on any buttons? I also want the auto refresh the middleContent without blinking the page. I don't want the page to auto refresh back to the default view, but it'll auto refresh and stays in the same View...

I wanted to set it like let's say auto refresh after 10 seconds... I have tried the following code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var idleInterval = setInterval ("reloadPage()", 10000) //10 seconds

function reloadPage() {
    location.reload();
}
</script>
```

It does reload the page but it's blinking so is it possible to reload without the page blinking?

I'm a newbie in coding and isn't so sure how to use Timer in C# coding.. I have tried the following code snippet below too, but it doesn't seems to work... (The following below coding is found via Google..)

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Interval = 5000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
aTimer.Start();

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e){
    // some code here
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to refresh only one part of a page read about AJAX. using it you can get from the server data needed to render your page part or even render it on the server and intsert html wherever you need.

Comment: you can use `AJAX` for partial postback/partial rendering. [this](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use normal Panel instead of UpdatePanel? :)